# openxml .net 4.5 lib with .net core 2.2

Tags: .net-core, openxml, openxml-sdk, .net-4.6.1, system.io.packaging

I am receiving a `System.Io.FileNotFoundException` with the assembly `System.IO.Packaging` when trying to use my **.Net 4.6.1 Library** that was working fine with my **ConsoleApp**.

I am trying to use this same library with a **c#.Net core 2.2 Console Application**, but it is not working as you can see by viewing the snippet below.

How can I get the **.Net 4.6.1 Library**  to work with a **c#.Net core 2.2 2.2 Console Application**?

**See below:**

Click on image to enlarge
[image: Error Description]

Solution (projects + NuGet Packages) :

- OpenXml Libraby c# .Net 4.6.1

  - Nuget : DocumentFormat.OpenXml (2.9.0)
  - Nuget : System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (4.3.0)
  - Nuget : System.IO.Packaging     (4.5.0)
- ConsoleApplication  c#.Net core 2.2

Comment: You cannot use a full framework library with a .net core application. You will need to retarget your library to use Net Standard.

Comment: The SDK for .NET Core has been out for long, https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/191